Current control BLDC motor
I was looking at the control mechanisms of BL (brushless) DC motors and the majority of the content is focused on speed control. Is it possible to set a given current (torque) to control without explicitly controling the motion speed?

if you can measure it, then you can control its value

Is it possible questions are rarely useful.

The answer to the question is yes you can know torque, if you have a way to measure or estimate the current (usually you already know the voltage). At the end of the day if torque isn't measured, you can estimate it by the energy going into the motor (minus some efficiency). Its a system of equations so you can measure the power into the motor, or know something about the speed with an encoder.

Source: https://www.tytorobotics.com/blogs/articles/brushless-motor-power-and-efficiency-analysis
